# Regular expression for multiselect in DataTables table column

Tags: regex, datatables

Неllo! 

I'm using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) and I added multiselect to filter values ​​in a table column. Multiselect contains following values:

- Round one
- Round one closed
- Round two
- Round two closed

I created simple regex for filtering. But it's not working properly:


`$("thead th.checkbox_filter").each( function ( i ) {`

```
                this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect();
                $('select', this).change( function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == null) {
                        dataTable.fnFilter("", i);
                    } else {
                        var input = $(this).val();
                        var inputRegExp = "";
                        for (var k = 0; k < input.length; k++)
                        {
                            inputRegExp += input[k];
                            if (k != input.length - 1) {
                                inputRegExp += "|";
                            }
                        }
                        dataTable.fnFilter(inputRegExp, i, true, false);
                    }
                } );
            } );
```

If user selects "Round one" and "Round two" it also finds "Round one closed" and "Round two closed". Please help!

Comment: You should provide HTML code too.

Comment: if it's pure regexp (sorry don't know the jquery-databases functions) how about adding `$` after your `inputRegExp`?

Comment: Yes! adding $ helps, sorry for the question then :) Thank you!